# vertical asymptote - is it possible to have one like this?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology

If my function is defined for $x > 2$ and the question asks for vertical asymptotes, do I need to write $x = 2$ as an answer? Or no?

Comment: yes for example $1/\sqrt{x-2}$

Comment: so how do I know if I need to check or not?

Comment: Or $f(x)=\frac{1}{x-2}$, where $f$ is defined on $(2,\infty)$.

Comment: What do you think? Try drawing (from right to left) always upwards, approaching $x=2$ without ever touching it.

Comment: how do you know if you need to check what?!

Comment: @George I mean, if the questions asks for vertical asymptote, do I need to write that as an answer? Or no because the function is only defined for $x > 2$

Comment: @DanBarnet  vertical asymptote is always point of discontinuity where limits are $=\infty$. In your case function is defined only from one side of an asymptote, so you write $\lim_{x\rightarrow 2+0}f(x) = \infty$ or $-\infty$.

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: @DanBarnet The domain of $\frac{1}{x}$ is $\mathbb{R}\backslash \{0\}$, but everyone says that it has a vertical asymptote at $x=0$. So my vote is yes. Asymptote doesn't belong to function's domain, it's about the graphics behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on your definition of "vertical asymptote". Unfortunetaly, many authors (and teachers, and [online encyclopedias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptote)) don't give a careful definition. If possible, it's a good idea to check with your instructor.

Absent further information, if you have a continuous, real-valued function $f$ with domain $(2, \infty)$ and if
$$
\lim_{x \to 2^{+}} f(x) = \infty\quad\text{or}\quad
\lim_{x \to 2^{+}} f(x) = -\infty,
$$
then it's reasonable to call $x = 2$ a vertical asymptote of the graph $y = f(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that **the vertical asymptote is not the function or even part of the function**. It's a line that a point on a curve (aka your function) approaches as its horizontal position becomes arbitrarily close to $2$.

Just to reiterate (*reiterate*: is the redundant?): **the vertical asymptote is not the function**.